# why .play and .fixedPlayer show error " isn't defined."? But Audioplayers already add as dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-player, dart-pub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iq7B.png)
I dont understand why this error occur, is my code have any problem?

***The error***

*The named parameter 'fixedPlayer' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'fixedPlayer'.*

*The method 'play' isn't defined for the type 'AudioCache'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'play'.*

main.dart

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _counter = '';

  ///Audio player
  AudioPlayer? audioPlayer;
  late AudioCache audioCache;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
      audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      audioCache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);
    });
  }

  void playAudio() {
    audioPlayer!.stop();

    audioCache.play('music.mp3');
  }

  void stopAudio() {
    audioPlayer!.stop();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioPlayer!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    audioPlayer!.getCurrentPosition().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value.toString();
      });
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: playAudio,
            tooltip: 'Play',
            child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: stopAudio,
            tooltip: 'Stop',
            child: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          ),
        ],
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^1.0.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.17
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.17.1
  flame: ^1.0.0-rc7
  flame_audio: ^1.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  just_audio: ^0.9.25
  provider: ^6.0.3
  shared_preferences_web: ^2.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  flutter_carousel_slider: ^1.0.8
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide source to play and play method can be call on `AudioPlayer`

```dart
audioPlayer!.play(AssetSource("music.mp3"));
```

You can check the [documentation of  audioplayers](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md)

```dart
  ///Audio player
  AudioPlayer? audioPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    audioPlayer!.setSourceAsset("");
  }

  void playAudio() async {
    await audioPlayer!.stop();
    audioPlayer!.play(AssetSource("music.mp3"));
  }

  void stopAudio() {
    audioPlayer?.stop();
  }
```